# Get values of variables during warning inside for-loop (R)

Tags: r, loops, warnings

I'm trying to batch convert a bunch of files as follows:

```
library(foreign)

for(dtaf in dir(recursive=TRUE,pattern="\\.dta$")){
  write.csv(read.dta(dtaf),paste0(substr(dtaf,1,nchar(dtaf)-3),"csv"))
  gc()
}
```

However, once the loop is done, I get the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
2: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
3: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to retrieve the value of `dtaf` (the file being currently written) so I can manually examine it and see if there's any actual issue with the data.

Comment: It worked, thanks! However, it only points at two files even though there are three warnings. Any idea about how that's supposed to work?

Comment: Maybe one of the files results in two warnings? It looks like the warning is triggered by a particular column, so if two columns in one file have the issue two warnings would be reasonable.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks, really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tryCatch` is most commonly used for catching errors, but it can also be used for warnings.

Something like

```
 tryCatch(write.csv(<your code>), warning = function(w) print(dtaf))
```

will `print(dtaf)` whenever there is a warning. You could make the warning function as elaborate as you would like, maybe printing out the warning too, adding the warning and the `dtaf` value to a list for later review, etc.